# Сравнение списка с несколькими на вхождение значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, списки, numpy

Даны список

```
lst_1 = [114170, 113970]
```

и список с вложенными массивами

```
lst_2 = [(array([114250, 114240, 114230, 114220, 114210, 114200, 114190, 114180,
         114170, 114160, 114150, 114140, 114130, 114120, 114110, 114100,
         114090]),
  array([114080, 114070, 114060, 114050]),
  array([114040, 114030, 114020, 114010, 114000, 113990, 113980, 113970,
         113960, 113950, 113940, 113930, 113920, 113910, 113900, 113890,
         113880]))]
```

Подскажите как найти вхождение значений из lst_1 в каждом подмассиве lst_2. Если значение содержится например в подмассиве lst_2[0], то вывести номер массива. Если значения содержаться в разных подмассивах, то аналогично вывести номера массивов. Количество значений в lst_1 и lst_2 могут быть разными, но количество подмассивов в lst_2 всегда одинаково.

Comment: Что такое array()?

Comment: Т.е. `lst_2` состоит из единственного `tuple`, который содержит `numpy arrays` - я правильно понял структуру ваших данных?

Comment: Да структура данных такая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, т.е. если:

> `lst_2` состоит из единственного `tuple`, который содержит `numpy arrays`

Решение:

```
In [79]: res = [i for i,x in enumerate(lst_2[0]) if np.intersect1d(x, lst_1).size > 0]
```

Результат:

```
In [80]: res
Out[80]: [0, 2]
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо